# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. Error using react-hook-form within App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I'm trying to code in App.js using react hook forms, but I keep running into the error. My goal for the app is just a simple sign up form so that I can save the user's data into a JSON and save it to my database. React Hook Form makes this process pretty easy, but I can't figure out how to use hooks to pass information between the two javascript files.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPook.png)

At the moment, my App.js looks like

```html
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useForm} from "react-hook-form";
import SignUp from "./views/SignUp/SignUp";

const App = (props) => {

    const {register, handleSubmit, errors} = useForm();


    return (
        <div>
            <SignUp

                register = {register}
                handleSubmit = {handleSubmit}
                errors = {errors}



            />

        </div>
    );
};


export default App;
```

and my SignUp.js looks like

```html
import React from 'react';

const SignUp = (props) => {




    const onSubmit = (data) => {

        console.log(data);
    };



    return (
        <form onSubmit={props.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <input type="text" placeholder="First name" name="First name" ref={props.register({required: true, maxLength: 80})} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last name" name="Last name" ref={props.register({required: true, maxLength: 100})} />
            <input type="datetime" placeholder="Date Of Birth" name="Date Of Birth" ref={props.register} />
            <input type="search" placeholder="Location of Birth" name="Location of Birth" ref={props.register} />
            <input type="time" placeholder="Time of Birth" name="Time of Birth" ref={props.register} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="Email" ref={props.register({required: true, pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i})} />
            <input type="tel" placeholder="Mobile number" name="Mobile number" ref={props.register({required: true, minLength: 6, maxLength: 12})} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username" ref={props.register} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Password" name="Password" ref={props.register} />
            <input type="submit" />

        </form>
    );

};

export default SignUp;
```

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: Are the default hooks like `useState` and `useEffect` working?

Comment: @LawrenceWitt Yes, I just tested useState and it worked as intended.

Comment: Have you tested it in one component? I've just been reading the docs and it seems like you would have to use [FormContext](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#useFormContext) to split across different components.

Comment: I tried just to abandon the <SignUp/> component altogether and paste the code that was in the return() in the return() in App.js, but that didn't work either. I didn't see FormContext in the documentation before, so I can try and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I tested your code together in one component on a codesandbox and it worked fine. If you're getting the same error for one component on your own machine then I can only assume it is something to do with the installation of `react-hook-form`. [This](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/59) is the only reference to your issue I could find on their github. You could try reinstalling it on your project and installing on a fresh React app if that fails, just to be sure that the config is all set up correctly.